# How to implement SSO into safari-app-extension without POPOVER toolbar action

Tags: javascript, swift, single-sign-on, safari-app-extension

I am trying to make `SSO` auth in my `safari-app-extension`. And the only way which I found that is creating `WKWebView` and getting secured cookies from inside. But there are two problems. The first that this is not really SSO, because `WKWebView` and safari have separated cookie storage. And the second one I don't need POPOVER tollbar item action (all UI composes inside a page).  Is there any way to get a seсured cookie from the safari page? Or at least is there any way to invoke/not-to-invoke popover conditionally?
I didn't have the same problem in old safari extensions because browser cookies were shared with the background part.